# How to restore deleted file?

Tags: restore

Guy's I'm here with another problem.I delete my most important folders.It is also delete from trash folder.How do i restore.If anyone know where those files is please help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **stop** using that drive right now, as using it will make it less probable the data recovery.

[Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is a great tool a great tool for data recovery among other things. Please take the time to read the documentation for the data recovery section. Hope this helps. Don't hesitate to ask again! Cheers